# Recuperar value do input data

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Como recupero o value do input data? Meu objetivo é o value ser conforme a data selecionada no campo.

[image: Campo para filtrar]

Campo do filtro:

```
<div class="filt-nam">
        <h5>Filtrar Itinerários por Data: </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataInicio" value="" />
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataFim" value="" />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onclick="filtrarData()">Filtrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Arquivo JS:

```
function filtrarData() {
    let dataInicio = document.getElementById('dataInicio')
    let dataFim = document.getElementById('dataFinal')

    console.log(dataInicio.value, dataFim.value)
};
```

Comment: Vc trocou `dataFim` por `dataFinal`.

Comment: A final, qual o real objetivo da pergunta? É corrigir o erro de um único campo, como o [Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam) mencionou e o [André Filipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/127729/andr%c3%a9-filipe) respondeu ou formatar o campo, como o [Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296/luiz-felipe) respondeu? Qual o erro apresentado? O que acontece de forma inesperada? Deveria apontar seu objetivo pra evitar perguntas do tipo "chute"...

Comment: Vamos aguardar a resposta do [Felipe Noka](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/138171/felipe-noka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data), o `<input>` do tipo `date` sempre retornará uma *string* no formato `AAAA-MM-DD`, ou seja, ano, mês e dia.

Você precisa criar uma função para transformar a data no formato `AAAA-MM-DD` para `DD/MM/AAAA`:

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#date-field')

function formatDate(date) {
  const [, year, month, day] = date.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/)
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
}

field.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(`Sem formatação: ${event.target.value}`)
  console.log(`Com formatação: ${formatDate(event.target.value)}`)
})
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-field" />
```

#### Referência:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data

Answer (score 2):

> Como recupero o value do input data?

Fazendo uma breve análise de seu código vi que está estruturado corretamente, porém, na segunda variável `dataFim` você está dando um `document.getElementById('dataFinal')`, uma vez que esse `Id` não existe em seu código *HTML* o `console.log` irá lançar a seguinte exceção pois a sua variável `dataFim` estará nula:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Você poderia alterar o seu código *Javascript* para:

```
let dataFim = document.getElementById('dataFim')
```

ou seu *HTML* para:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataFinal" value="" />
```